# What does it mean for a container to have a running state?

Tags: container, podman

When I run `podman create` followed by `podman exec`, I'm told that my container state is not running,

```
$ ctr=$(podman create alpine:3)
dc63e5975a918485b3d6a0ddf90576213b02d00e15fd84bab97732cf6d1f885a
$ podman exec -ti $ctr /bin/sh
Error: can only create exec sessions on running containers: container state improper
```

What does it mean to have a container without a running state? Is there a method to set the state on the container, it seems `podman exec` does not work even after I start the contianer.

```
$ podman start $ctr
dc63e5975a918485b3d6a0ddf90576213b02d00e15fd84bab97732cf6d1f885a
$ podman exec -ti $ctr /bin/sh
Error: can only create exec sessions on running containers: container state improper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

;tldr: A container is "running" if a process inside is running. A process is running only when a `Created` container is started and the state is `Up`

---

If you create a container with `podman create` the state is `Created`,

```
$ podman create alpine:3
d02b4e268fd4bb4a816852efd2e032069402474237e7bea6b3708b0319e9c318

$ podman container ls -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND         CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                   NAMES
d02b4e268fd4  docker.io/library/alpine:latest  /bin/sh         8 seconds ago       Created                                               exciting_hofstadter
```

Now, you can start with this with `podman start`, but it won't stay in that state it'll instantly exit,

```
$ podman start d02b4e268fd4
d02b4e268fd4
$ podman container ls -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND         CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                   NAMES
d02b4e268fd4  docker.io/library/alpine:latest  /bin/sh         21 seconds ago      Exited (0) 5 seconds ago                              exciting_hofstadter
```

The solution here is to have a long running process in it,

```
# status created
$ podman create -ti alpine:3 /bin/sh
```

Now the status is `Up`

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND         CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                   NAMES
cefa530172e3  docker.io/library/alpine:latest  /bin/sh         About a minute ago  Up 25 seconds ago                                     musing_cohen
```

And now you can `exec` in it,

```
$ podman exec cefa530172e3 /bin/echo "Hello World"
Hello World
```

Comment: If you just want to run a single command in this environment, you can do it all in one line: `podman run alpine:3 echo "Hello World"`. This will create the container, run your command and exit.

Comment: No, I don't just want to do that. I want to understand how these commands work.

Answer (score 1):

```
create      Create but do not start a container
exec        Run a process in a running container
```

Exec does not start your container. You'd want to use `start` or `run` for this.

If it isn't working despite that, your conatiner probably crashed or exited before you were able to run your `exec` command. If your main process exits, your container will do so as well, also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214133/2519977

As a minimal test you may want to try:

```
ctr=$(podman create alpine:3)
podman run -d -it $ctr /bin/sh
```

Comment: I can obviously do that. What is `podman create` doing though if I can't take the containers that I create, and start them? How do I start a container with `podman create`

Comment: You dont start a container with `create` (as mentioned above). It depends on what exactly you're trying to do. But if you want to run something specfic, you can specify that in [create](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-create.1.html) and use start - otherwise use `run` or use a `dockerfile` with an `entrypoint`.

Comment: "you can specify that in create and use start" could you show an example of this?

Comment: `podman container create alpine:3 tail -f /dev/null` for example, but it does nothing of course.

Comment: here is a follow up: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620893/where-does-the-output-go-to-the-command-specified-in-podman-create