# Where does the output go to the command specified in `podman create`?

Tags: stdout, podman

If I create a container with `podman create`, I can't seem to find any series of options that show the output of the command I'm running. For example, here we can run a container with "Hello World"

```
$ podman run alpine:3 /bin/echo "Hello World"
Hello World
```

But, if I change that to

```
$ ctr=$(podman create alpine:3 /bin/echo "Hello World")
$ podman start $ctr
```

Nothing is outputted to the screen, the status does show `Exited`,

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS                       PORTS                   NAMES
cc31f5a3cc95  docker.io/library/alpine:latest  /bin/echo Hello W...  14 seconds ago  Exited (0) 14 seconds ago                            modest_raman
```

I've tried different options to `podman create`, including `-t`, `-i`, and `-ti`, all with the same effects. Where does the output go?

```
ctr=$(podman create -ti alpine:3 /bin/echo "[ti] Hello World")
podman start $ctr

ctr=$(podman create -t alpine:3 /bin/echo "[t] Hello World")
podman start $ctr

ctr=$(podman create -i alpine:3 /bin/echo "[i]Hello World")
podman start $ctr
```

I've also tried with `podman start -i` (though at this point I'm just getting desperate)

Comment: `podman start -a $ctr` (You don't really need `-i` here). `podman start --help`

Comment: @rudib seed that as an answer, I'll improve it and mark it as accepted. That's all it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from state, `podman run` will start containers **attached**,

```
$ podman run alpine:3 /bin/echo "Hello World"
Hello World
```

However, `podman start` starts them **detached**, but it provides the following option,

> `--attach`, `-a` Attach container's `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.  The default is false. This option cannot be used when starting multiple containers.

So you need only

```
ctr=$(podman create alpine:3 /bin/echo "Hello World")
podman start --attach $ctr
```